# c# binary search method " Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException:"

Tags: c#, json, binary-search

Having trouble getting this binary search result to convert to int. All the code functions well up to this point. I'd like to take in a name and display the contents from the json instantiation. I've already placed the sort.  Thanks

"Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
 static void SearchEntity(Entity[] entities)
    {
            Entities result = new Entities();
            Console.WriteLine("Which name to find ");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] title = new string[10000];

 //-------------
            Console.Write("Search Keyword : ");
            string searchKeyword = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userInput.ToLower() == "title")
            {
               title = entities.Select(m => m.Title).ToArray();

                Array.Sort(title);
                Sorting.Sort(entities, userInput);                                                 

                var tmp = Array.BinarySearch<string>(title, userInput);



                if (Convert.ToInt32(tmp) == -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No data found!");
                    return;
                }
                result = entities[Convert.ToInt32(tmp)];
                entitiesPrint(result);
            }
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for BinarySearch to see how it works. It returns an `int`. That `int` can be any negative number, not just -1.

Comment: I have to ask, why use a binary search here at all? They work best on an array that is already sorted, but if you have to manually sort the array before performing the search then you lose the performance benefits.

Comment: I'm just recently learning out how to use binary search.   So, it's returning negative values, which means I'm confusing the sort...?

Comment: @seems See my answer. The negative number it returns contains information on what the search found - it's not going to just be `-1`.

Comment: put the code after the 'if' in an else so it doesn't run when -1 is returned.

Comment: @jdweng The if statement contains an `return`, so that wouldn't happen anyway.

Comment: Thanks all, it's running well now

Comment: Now I'm looking for how to get rid of the Array.BinarySearch and impliment the method containing the algorithm... Any Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Array.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> The index of the specified value in the specified array, if value is found; otherwise, a negative number. If value is not found and value is less than one or more elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value. If value is not found and value is greater than all elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of (the index of the last element plus 1). If this method is called with a non-sorted array, the return value can be incorrect and a negative number could be returned, even if value is present in array.

On not finding an exact value, the method can return all sorts of negative numbers, not just -1. You are going to want to use the following instead:

```
if (tmp < 0) 
    // ...
```

It's also worth noting that `Array.BinarySearch` returns an `int` already, so the call to `Convert.ToInt32` is redundant.